# How do i use ansible modules in preview?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-elb

I am trying to use the `elb_target_group` and `elb_application_lb` modules which according to the doc website states `New in version 2.4` and current ansible version is 2.3

So how do i use these modules in preview mode?

When i add them to my playbook and try to run i get the following

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

- elb_target_group:
  ^ here
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to preview an Ansible playbook you should use it on a Vagrant box.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "preview mode". You need to install appropriate Ansible version. The instructions for installing from the GitHub repository are published [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source):

> To install from source, clone the Ansible git repository:
>
> ```
> $ git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
> $ cd ./ansible
> $ source ./hacking/env-setup
> ```

On top of that, you seem to be lacking a colon after module's name.

Comment: that is how error message came, i did not miss any colon. Also there is no ansible 2.4 so how can i get that from github? i also don't see any 2.4 in your command. thanks!

Comment: Read the manual and use your reasoning. Also, you did not post any code, so no one can really tell if you missed something, or not.

Comment: read the manual for what exactly? do you want to really help OR want to be tricky here?

Comment: I gave you the link to the manual, I am not going to translate the official docs into Simple English.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/elb_target_group_module.html and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/elb_application_lb_module.html both says `New in version 2.4` AND ansible latest version is 2.3..even on github.

Comment: ok cool..never mind then..thought you wanted to be helpful..i know there was documentation before posting here..so thanks for your time..peace